# Create CellFactory based on row item

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I try to create `TableColumn` with `ChoiceBoxTableCell`. Choices in this `ChoiceBox` are dynamically generated (and changed over time) based on item associate with current row. I tried different approaches, but nothing seems to work.

I would like to have something like this:

```
private DataProvider dataProvider;
private TableColumn<Phone, String> testColumn;

public void initialize() {
    testColumn.setCellFactory(param, phone -> new ChoiceBoxTableCell<Phone, String>(dataProvicer.get(phone)));
}
```

Where:

```
public interface DataProvider {
    ObservableList<String> get(Phone phone);
}
```

This is my *ideal* code I would like to have, but as you know `setCallFactory` takes `Callback` with `TableColumn<S,T>` as function parameter and there is no way to access it within `CellFactory`. I could probably do some dirty and ugly hacks to get why I want, but I would love to have some nice solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A reminder of the basic mechanism: a cellFactory is used to create *any* cell of for the given column. The calling code (that is the VirtualFlow deep inside the implementation of table's skin) isn't interested in or don't event know which row the cell is created for. Also, it will be re-used - that is setting a new item - quite often. In all, the moment of creating the cell is not the right time to configure the cell with *row-related* data. This has to be done later, once the row is known: the most obvious candidate is `updateItem(T, boolean)`.

Now back to the concrete ChoiceBoxTableCell: unfortunately, its implementation is too dumb and simply doesn't support dynamic updates of its choice items. So you need a custom extension which does support the dynamics. On the bright side: ChoiceBoxTableCell exposes its items, thus allowing to change its contents as needed.

As noted in the code comment, it turned out that the obvious hook didn't work out nicely. So had to move the config into the startEdit method.

Some code:

```
public interface ChoiceItemProvider<S, T> {
    ObservableList<T> getItems(S source);
}

public class DynamicChoiceBoxTableCell<S, T> extends ChoiceBoxTableCell<S, T> {

    private ChoiceItemProvider<S, T> provider;

    public DynamicChoiceBoxTableCell(ChoiceItemProvider<S, T> provider) {
        super();
        this.provider = provider;
    }


    /**
     * Not so obvious hook: overridden to update the items of the 
     * choiceBox.
     */
    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        super.startEdit();
        updateItems();
    }

    /**
     * Obvious hook: override to update the items of the choiceBox.
     * Not fully working - for some reason, the current item isn't
     * selected after starting the edit.
     */
    @Override
    public void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        // updateItems();
    }

    /**
     * Dynamically updates the items to current rowItem. 
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected void updateItems() {
        TableRow<S> tableRow = getTableRow();
        S rowItem = tableRow != null ? tableRow.getItem() : null;
        if (provider == null || rowItem == null) return;
        if (provider != null) {
            getItems().setAll(provider.getItems(rowItem));
        } 
    }
}
```

Addendum re:

> no ideal, because items won't be updated when it is already expanded

If you need that, you can bind the choiceBox' items to the items returned by the provider, that is instead of calling `setAll(provider.getItems())` do:

```
Bindings.bindContent(getItems(), provider.getItems());
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I thought about this solution, but is still is no ideal, because items won't be updated when it is already expanded. For my case in really a big deal, but in other cases it might be. I would be happy when there would be additional listeners (one for row and one for cell) when we can do additional binding like binding row disable property to designated property from specific row item

Answer (score -1):

```
testColumn.setCellFactory(ChoiceBoxTableCell.forTableCoulmn(<dynamic list>));
```

This should work.

Comment: not really - at least as I understand the requirement, my understanding might be wrong of course :-) The list is dynamic relative to the row data, which isn't known at its creation. In fact, it's not known at any time except when really bound to an item.

Comment: At some point you will be knowing the list which should be displayed. Populate the list just then and add this as next statement

Comment: @NaveenBharadwaj The point is it's a different list for each cell. You just have a single `cellFactory` for the whole column. So there is no way to know what to pass in as an argument here.

Comment: You don't need a workaround. There's a perfectly good solution provided by @kleopatra